# More than one CT in a Library with Custom Forms

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, content-type, custom-form, form

Let's say I have a Library A, and this library has B and C as content types.
B and C have their own custom forms.

So When a Library has more than one content type in the (default) form of the default CT you will see a dropdown where you can choose what CT you are using for that specific document.

How can I get that dropdown if I'm using custom forms?

Comment: If "A" is a Document Library, have You (in Advanced Settings for the library) activated "Allow management of content types"?

Comment: Yes I have it activated... The thing is I'm using custom forms... What is the internal name for that dropdown? So I can call it throught my form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research time I found the way to show that little dropdown :)
You have to include in your custom form this:

```
<SharePoint:ChangeContentType runat="server" id="ContentType_" ControlMode="Edit"/>
```

In order to be able to select the content type you want for your item